# Autoplay slideshow not working when open in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

**owl.carousel.js** plugin used for jquery slideshow, at the first time this slide show work correctly but when I open a new tab in firefox or chrome, I see that auto play slideshow not working.

Demo : http://minimoviez.info/
Demo : https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
   owl.owlCarousel({
       items: 5,
       loop:true,
       margin: 10,
       autoplay: true,
        stopOnHover : false,
       autoplayTimeout: 1000,
       responsive:false,
       dots: false
   });

   $('.play').on('click', function () {
       owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay', [1000])
   });
   $('.stop').on('click', function () {
       owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay')
   });
});
```

Comment: Can you upload working demo here.

Comment: this is a demo  https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been reported and has been fixed in the new version. [bug reported link](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/1727)
Just update the script to the latest version.
This link:
[Owl Carousel v2.3.0](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/develop/dist/owl.carousel.min.js)

Comment: tnx ,I took a lot of time For it

Comment: I checked your website, you are using v2.2.1 now!

Comment: when i see that this version not work, i use older version ,are you sure this version was correct?

Comment: Yes, I tested. [See this link](http://legaltext.ir/test.html). _after seeing, please tell me to remove the link._

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to remove the trigger by clicking "play" and "stop" buttons that you don't have.

Maybe you'll need to keep `owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay', [1000]);` in your document ready function.

Try it. Right now i cannot download the plugin to try.

Comment: hi my friend , I also tried this but when i open a new tab this not work and stopped ,

Answer (score 0):

my problem was solved by this code

setInterval(function(){ owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay', [1000]); }, 24000);

i don't know that why this problem accord , but by this code was resolved